# Configure Bamboo for Android Gradle based Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bamboo, gradlew

I am trying to setup Bamboo for my **Gradle** build system based **Android Project.** 
I have done the following setup on Bamboo.I'm done with rest of all setup upto project repository path.

I want to run the following tasks using gradlew for android

**clean assembleDebug LintDebug**

For that I have created new task called **Gradle Wrapper**.
Below is the Gradle Wrapper Configuration

[image]

When I am executing gradle wrapper task, I am getting the following error.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find executable 'D:\AndroidDemo\gradle-2.10\bin\gradlew.bat'

**Note** :- Standalone Gradle is working fine on local machine with all the tasks(**clean assembleDebug LintDebug)**

Gradle_Home = D:\AndroidDemo\gradle-2.10\bin(Local machine)

Can anyone suggest a solution for the same?

Answer (score 2):

I also had some initial difficulties to set up Bamboo to build an Android project using Gradle.

First of all, make sure that you have the Gradle wrapper (`gradlew`) in your repo. (Seemingly that's the situation in your case). *It seems to me, however the Gradle wrapper ignores the system default Gradle distribution (set by the `GRADLE_HOME` env var), and always downloads a Gradle version mandated by the Android Build tools.*

Also make sure, that the Android SDK root environment variable (`ANDROID_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`) is pointing to the SDK's root directory (e.g. `$ export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk/"`)[[1]](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables).

Restart Bamboo after applying the environment variable changes.

In Bamboo, in the build tasks lists, add a new **Script** task. The interpreter should be '/bin/sh or cmd.exe', the script location should be 'inline', and the script body should contain the call for the parametrized Gradle wrapper, e.g.

`gradlew clean build`

Point the working subdirectory to the Gradle wrapper's relative location (to the repo root), if necessary.

[[Sample Bamboo Android Gradle build script]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKN8Y.png)

After these steps, Bamboo should execute the Gradle wrapper, which in fact should perform the actual build steps.